# bzr revno not displaying checked out revision

Tags: linux, version-control, bazaar

When I type `bzr revno` in the project directory, it displays for me the latest version I've received from my last `bzr update` rather than what I've `revert`ed to most recently. Obviously `bzr` is more worried about what I've checked out, rather than the code revision I'm working with.

This is also the case if I do `bzr update -rN`.

For example:

```
patrick@blendtec:~/Project$ bzr update                                                                                                            
Tree is up to date at revision 743 of branch bzr+ssh://patrick@ninja/Project                                                                  
patrick@blendtec:~/Project$ bzr revert -r 720
 M  makefile
 M  file.cpp
 M  file.h
-D  other_file.h
patrick@blendtec:~/Project$ bzr revno                                                                                                             
743
patrick@blendtec:~/Project$ bzr revno --tree
743
```

So... what command does one use to display the revision number of the code that's been reverted to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
bzr revno --tree
```

to get the revision number of the current working tree. Alternatively, you can also use `bzr version-info` with an appropriate template, e.g.:

```
bzr version-info --custom --template='{revno}\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but both of those give me the version I've got checked out, not the version I've reverted to.

Comment: I've amended my post to illustrate the issue more clearly.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of `bzr revert`. Reverting to a revision will change the state of the working tree (either all or some of the files), but not the version of the working tree itself, which remains unchanged. Consider that you can revert some files from one version and the remaining files from another version; the working tree will correspond to neither of them.

Comment: That is a fine point, and I appreciate the insight. I suppose then I'd want to use something like the revision number of a specific file, but it doesn't look like `bzr revno` supports that granularity. Is there a solution that you're aware of to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, this information is not something that Bazaar – or any other version control system I can think of – tracks. It's simply not something that they are designed for, as modern VCSs (post CVS) tend to think in terms of atomic modifications of the entire working tree, not parts of it.